# Submodule over ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I am calculating submodules of module $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$.

Consider $I=(x^3+x+1)$ ideal generated by $x^3+x+1$.

Elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)=\{0+I,1+I,x+I,x^2+I,x^2+x+I,x^2+1+I,x+1+I,x^2+x+I\}$

I only get one non trivial submodule which is $\{0+I,1+I\}$, does there any other non trivial submodule?

Comment: $\{0+I,1+I\}$ is not submodule over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$. It is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Yeah right damm i forgot! Can give one proper submodule!

Comment: The congruence class of $0$, for instance. That's all, because $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbf F_2$, so your module is actually a field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that, as per third isomorphism theorem, the submodules of $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ correspond to submodules of $\mathbb Z_2[x]$ containing the submodule $(x^3+x+1)$.

Now, also recall that $Z_2[x]$-submodules of $Z_2[x]$ are nothing else than *ideals* of $Z_2[x]$, and, being a PID, ideals containing $(x^3+x+1)$ correspond to principal ideals corresponding to *divisors* of $x^3+x+1$ over $\mathbb Z_2[x]$.

However, $x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_2[x]$, being of degree $3$ and having no zeros. Thus, the only ideals of $Z_2[x]$ containing $(x^3+x+1)$ are $(x^3+x+1)$ and $Z_2[x]$ itself. This means there will be no nontrivial submodules of $\mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$.